# Java - Creating Object Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I can't seem to work out these object arrays, I'm attempting to create a list of player names with values stored, each with an integer and some multiple strings for each.

This is what i'm working on so far, were object arrays the correct storage package for this? The error was in line 237 when I try to add a player in the class addPlayer: player[userCount].setName(name);

The error is:- Exception in thread "main" index out of bounds.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayerKarma {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static private String[] username = {"name1","name2","test","moretesting","fervor","stackoverflow","imported","quaternion","jetstream"};
    static private int[] karma = {1000,800,800,5,15,-4,-403,54,11,210};
    static private boolean exit = false;
    static private int maxKarmaChange = 10; //How much a players karma can change per day.
    static Player[] userArray = new Player[10000];
    //ArrayList<Player> userArray = new ArrayList<Player>();
    static private int userCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        while (!exit)
        {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Select an option");
        System.out.println("1: Display a player's karma");
        System.out.println("3: Display all player names and karma");
        System.out.println("5: Add player");

        String command = input.nextLine();
        switch(command)
            {
            //Display player's karma.
            case "1": {
                System.out.println("Enter a player's name: ");
                String inputString = input.nextLine();
                int playerindex = findPlayer(inputString);

                if (playerindex == -1)
                    {
                    System.out.println("Player doesn't exist");
                    }
                else //If the player exists.
                    {
                    System.out.println(userArray[playerindex].getName() + " has a karma of " + karma[userArray[playerindex].getKarma()]);
                    break;
                    }

                break;}

            //Display all player names and karma.
            case "3": {getAllPlayerKarma(); sleep(1500); break;}

            //Add player.
            case "5": {
                System.out.println("Enter a player's name:");
                String inputString = input.nextLine();

                if (userCount > 0) //If there is at least one user in the database.
                {
                int playerindex = findPlayer(inputString);

                if (playerindex == -1)
                    {
                    addPlayer(inputString,0);
                    }
                else //If the player exists.
                    {
                    break;
                    }
                }
                else //If there's no users.
                {
                    addPlayer(inputString,0);
                }
                break;}
            }
        }
    }

    //Class creation for players.
    public class Player
    {
        public String name;
        public int karma;
        //public String[] notes = new String[5];

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getKarma() {
            return karma;
        }
        public void setKarma(int karma) {
            this.karma = karma;
        }
    }

    private static void getAllPlayerKarma() {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < userCount; k++)
        {
            System.out.println(userArray[k].getName() + " has a karma of " + userArray[k].getKarma());
        }
    }

    private static void setAllPlayerKarma(String karmaValue) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < username.length; k++)
        {
            int parseKarma = Integer.parseInt(karmaValue);
            karma[k] = parseKarma;
        }
        System.out.println("All karma has been set to " + karmaValue);
    }

    private static void addPlayer(String name, int karma) {
        //Adds a new user
        Player[] player = new Player[userCount];
        //Player[userCount] = new Player(userCount);

        player[userCount].setName(name);
        player[userCount].setKarma(karma);
        //userArray[userCount].setName(name);
        //userArray[userCount].setKarma(karma);
        userCount++;
    }

//Returns the index of the player in the database.
private static int findPlayer(String playerName) {
    int playerIndex = -1;

    for (int j = 0; j < userCount; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Testing name: " + playerName + " against " + userArray[j].getName());
        if (playerName.equals(userArray[j].getName())) {
            playerIndex = j;
            System.out.println("Match");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("No match");
        }
    }
    return playerIndex;
    }

private static void sleep(int sleep) {
    try {Thread.sleep(sleep);}
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah sorry, the error was: Exception in thread "main" index out of bounds

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems with this code:

```
Player[] player = new Player[userCount];
player[userCount].setName(name);
```

Firstly, you're creating a new array each time - I suspect you want to populate `userArray` instead.

Secondly, you're creating an array of size `userCount` and then trying to use the element with index `userCount` - that's never going to work. Array indexes are 0-based, so an element with length 3 has valid indexes 0, 1 and 2 for example.

Thirdly, you're not creating a new `Player` object - so every element in the array is null. Even if you fixed the index, `player[x].setKarma(karma)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

I suspect you want the method to look like this:

```
private static void addPlayer(String name, int karma) {
    Player player = new Player();
    player.setKarma(karma);
    player.setName(name);
    userArray[userCount] = player;
    userCount++;
}
```

That's now fine, until the user count exceeds the length of your array. At that point, you should start looking at `List<E>` (and `ArrayList<E>` in particular).

Comment: With the second error I thought I was creating the 10,000 sized array with: static Player[] userArray = new Player[10000]; Yes I did want to populate it instead. 

The "Player player = new Player(userCount);" is undefined after attempting it again with your code as a guide, wouldn't it be userArray instead of userCount there?

Comment: @FluidicIce: Yes, you're creating that array as well - but that wasn't the one you were populating - look at the code I quoted. It's not clear what you mean by "is undefined". That line doesn't use the array at all, it just creates a new object and stores a reference to it in a new local variable called `player`.

Comment: @FluidicIce: Ah, I see what was wrong. I was copying the constructor call from your commented out code, but it turns out that was broken. You don't have a parameterized constructor, so just call the parameterless one.

Comment: Ah I think i've got it working, I had to also move the 'Player' class into it's own class outside of PlayerKarma. I'll do some more research into these arrays, maps and lists too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize usercount with the value of 0 and therefore create an array with the size of 0 `Player[] player = new Player[userCount];`, this leads to your error.